# Failed to validate 'docker' driver (kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

when Every time I try to minikube start on Linux (ubuntu 18.04), I always get this Docker validation errors.[image]

Comment: You need to install docker for that - https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: thanks for the comment  but I already have docker installed

Comment: Please don't post error messages as an image, as it makes searching for similar error messages impossible; it's specifically mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 4):

This works fine for me:

```sh
myuser@mymachine:~$ minikube start --driver=docker
  minikube v1.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Found network options:
    ▪ NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.2 ...
    ▪ env NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254
    ▪ kubeadm.pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

Make sure that `/var/run/docker.sock` has the right permission to be accessed by your user

```sh
myuser@mymachine:~$ sudo chmod o+rw /var/run/docker.sock
myuser@mymachine:~$ ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 root docker 0 Jul  6 17:42 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Make sure the docker daemon is running:

```sh
myuser@mymachine:~$ ps -Af | grep dockerd
root     12723     1  0 Jul06 ?        00:01:11 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root     18598 17596  0 19:19 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --default-ulimit=nofile=1048576:1048576 --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=docker --insecure-registry 10.96.0.0/12
adminra+ 31177 26444  0 19:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dockerd
```